# Strange 404 error undefined.php

Tags: php, logging, server, http-status-code-404, undefined

I am facing strange 404 error for file undefined.php (which is not exist on server) in server log

```
[Thu Sep 21 10:08:48 2017] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File does not  exist: /home/user/public_html/undefined.php, referer: http://example.com/page1
```

There is no error in browser console, not any php error on server.
page1 has a form and which use php scripit also.
Is this any type of attack or something else ?
How can I so solve this ?

Comment: It would seem the file "undefined.php" does not exist in your directory root.

Comment: Is it an attack?  Maybe.   What is the IP address from the client?   Is it on any blacklists?

Comment: it could be an attack or error handling in page1 ?? When someone write something directly into a browsers address bar wich isn't available on your server, the document will not be found and the result will be an error 404.. Please post the source code from "page1" as this where the refferer it can help solving the issue....

Comment: This error occur for a page only and various IP addresses belong to Malaysia. Like - 175.145.59.177